# ST_Transform returning different results in PostGIS 2.4.3 and PostGIS 3.0.2

Tags: postgis-2.4, postgis-3.0

Getting this in 2.4.3

```
SELECT ST_AsText(ST_Transform(ST_SetSRID(ST_GeomFromText('POINT(-13279706.1692 5957543.84253624)'), 900913), 4326));
                 ST_AsText
 -------------------------------------------
 POINT(-119.293630204087 47.0946914247282)
(1 row)
```

And this in 3.0.2

```
SELECT ST_AsText(ST_Transform(ST_SetSRID(ST_GeomFromText('POINT(-13279706.1692 5957543.84253624)'), 900913), 4326));
-------------------------------------------
 POINT(-119.293630204087 47.2862076625893)
(1 row)
```

I've confirmed that the definitions for both 900913 and 4326 are identical in spatial_ref_sys. Not sure how to even go about troubleshooting this...

Comment: Try with 3857 not the obsolete 900913,

Comment: @IanTurton  Thank you!!! that did it. Please post as answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "900913" code is obsolete you should use 3857 instead.